# Display a div over a frame in html

Tags: html

Based on my requirement i need to display a div over a frame or frameset. Is it possible to display a div over a frame in an html page?

Comment: I have one frame in a frameset, like <frameset><frame width="" height=""/></frameset> <div class="">...</div> . I want to display this div over frame by setting z-index or something

Comment: No, iframe is always on top as far as I know. You'll have to first hide the frame, place the div over it and show the frame again when you hide the div.

Comment: not iframe i mean frame itself

Comment: I would try to avoid using frameset and frame if possible. You can make the similar thing with todays css features.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this page for information on managing frames technique with css only.

http://www.webpelican.com/web-tutorials/css-frames-tutorial/